# How to add nofollow filter to wordpress tags on single.php

Tags: wordpress, tags, nofollow

I want to be able to add a nofollow filter to my tags on single pages. I have this code that displays the tags...

> php if( tie_get_option( 'post_tags' ) ) the_tags( ''.__( 'Tagged with: ', 'tie' )  ,' ', '
>
> ');

what codes do I need to add so that the post tags (the_tags) are "nofollow"? Should I do it on single.php or on functions.php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to make your tags nofollow. Inner linking is usually a good thing.

But this is how you would do it.

You'll need to use this [wordpress function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) since it returns the output of the tags rather than displaying it. Then you need to iterate through the tags.

```
$tags = get_the_tags();

foreach($tags as $tag) {

    echo'<a href="' . $tag->slug . '" rel="nofollow">' . $tag->name . '</a>';

}
```

Not sure which file you would put this in. Mine was in `content.php`. It will depend on your theme. Check `single.php` if it's not there try `content.php`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and see if it works. I want my tags nofollow so that I could keep the link juice inside the current post. Thanks again.